# MySQL count column values equal to another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
Id  Id_1    Id_2
1     0   0
2     0   0
3     1   0
4     1   0
5     0   0
6     0   1
7     2   1
8     0   2
```

where Id_1 and Id_2 could be equal to Id except for itself or equal to 0

and I would like to get this result by using the most efficient query:

```
id    COUNT(Id_1)   COUNT(Id_2)
1         2             2
2         1             1
3         0             0
4         0             0
5         0             0
6         0             0
7         0             0
8         0             0
```

Thanks!

Comment: how do you mean 'except for itself?'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please seek guidance from the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Your question needs improvement. Please update with [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Please clarify this part: "where Id_1 and Id_2 could be equal to Id except for itself or equal to 0". It does not make sense. What exactly are you **counting** to get the result you want?

Comment: sorry, means that: if Id=1 -> Id_1 and Id_2 can't be equal to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation is not very clear, but based on your sample data and desired output you can accomplish this with two sub-queries outer joined to the base table, like this:

```
select a.id, 
  coalesce(b.id_1_count,0), 
  coalesce(c.id_2_count,0)
from so15273831 a
left outer join (
  select id_1, count(*) as id_1_count
  from so15273831
  group by id_1
) b on b.id_1 = a.id
left outer join (
  select id_2, count(*) as id_2_count
  from so15273831
  group by id_2
) c on c.id_2 = a.id
order by a.id;
```

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71b67/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE statement with subQueries to get your desired results

```
SELECT ID, SUM(id1.ids), SUM(id2.ids)
FROM mytable
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT id_1, count(id) ids
   FROM my table
   GROUP BY id_1) AS id1 ON mytable.ID = id1.id_1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT id_2, count(id) ids
   FROM my table
   GROUP BY id_2) AS id2  AS id2 ON mytable.ID = id2.id_2
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.id1 id,
(Select COUNT(*) From tableName t2 Where t1.id1=t2.id2) COUNT(Id_1),
(Select COUNT(*) From tableName t2 Where t1.id1=t2.id3) COUNT(Id_2)
 From tableName t1
```

Here is the alternate with example:

```
declare @aa table
(
 id1 int,
 id2 int,
 id3 int

)

insert into @aa
Select 
1,0,0
Union All Select
2,0,0
Union All Select
3,1,0
Union All Select
4,1,0
Union All Select
5,0,0
Union All Select
6,0,1
Union All Select
7,2,1
Union All Select
8,0,2

 Select t1.id1,IsNull(t2.CountId,0) as [Count(Id_2)],IsNull(t3.CountId,0) as [Count(Id_2)] From @aa t1
 Left Join 
 (
  Select COUNT(*) CountId,t2.id2 From @aa t2 Group By t2.id2
 )t2
 On t1.id1=t2.id2
 Left Join 
 (
  Select COUNT(*) CountId,t2.id3 From @aa t2 Group By t2.id3
 )t3 On t1.id1=t3.id3
```